# The xml attribute "id" seems to be a protected attribute. What config needed to be able to set it?

Tags: perl, xml-simple

I am using the perl module `XML::Simple` to create an XML structure.
Everything works fine except that the string `"<tag1 id="5"> ABC </tag1>"`
looks like `<tag1 name="5"> ABC </tag1>` afterwards.

I use the string with `XML::Simple` as follows

```
my $simple = XML::Simple->new();
my $tree = $simple->XMLin($my_xml_string, ForceArray => 1);

$resp->data()->{'xml'} = $tree;
```

The xml attribute `id` seems to be a protected attribute, because i get `name` in the output .

**What config is needed to be able to set it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `KeyAttr` option. You probably want `KeyAttr => []` to de-activate array to hash folding